# Error filesize() stat when downloading GPG file

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, filesize

my PHP program is supposed to write some data to a text file and encrypt the file using gnupg. When user press download, the program should download the encrypted file with .GPG extension.

I can encrypt and also decrypt the file successfully. But i'm seeing html code and error in my encrypted file. But it is gone right after i decrypt the file. But still it's considered as a bug is it? Can someone please help?

[Refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLvBb.png)

Part of my HTML code:

```
 <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="mt-4">Muat Turun Rekod</h1>
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:18px"></i>
                    Rekod untuk Dimuat Turun
                </div>
                <div class="card-body-tbm">

                    <form method="post" action="tryExport.php">
                        <div class=" table-responsive">
                            <table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Bil.</th>
                                        <th>ID </th>
                                        <th>Nama</th>
                                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                                        <th>PTJ</th>
                                        <th>Peringkat</th>
                                        <th>Peranan</th>
                                        <th>Modul</th>
                                        <th>Capaian</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Catatan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Catatan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Muat Turun <input type="checkbox"
                                                id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'chkbox[]')">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                     $j=0;
               
                                     $j=0;

                                     $result= query("SELECT NAME, NRIC, sc_jabatan.PERIHALJABATAN AS JABATAN, sc_ptj.PERIHALPTJ AS PTJ, sc_module.ABBRV AS MODULE, SC_PROGRAM, 
                                     ID_CAPAIAN_D, gd1.PERIHALCODE AS PERINGKAT, gd2.PERIHALCODE AS PERANAN, REMARK_APPROVE, REMARK_VERIFY 
                                     FROM user_main 
                                     JOIN user_capaian ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian.USER_MAIN_NRIC 
                                     JOIN user_capaian_d ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian_d.USER_MAIN_NRIC AND user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN=user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN
                                     JOIN gc_d gd1 ON gd1.ID=user_capaian.GC_LEVEL
                                     JOIN gc_d gd2 ON gd2.ID=user_capaian.GC_ROLE
                                     JOIN sc_module ON sc_module.ID=user_capaian_d.SC_MODULE
                                     JOIN user_history ON user_main.NRIC=user_history.USER_MAIN_NRIC AND
                                     user_capaian.USER_HISTORY_ID=user_history.ID AND user_capaian_d.USER_HISTORY_ID=user_history.ID
                                     JOIN sc_jabatan ON sc_jabatan.ID=user_capaian.SC_JABATAN
                                     JOIN sc_ptj ON sc_ptj.ID=user_capaian.SC_PTJ
                                     WHERE user_capaian_d.F_FILESTATUS='N' AND
                                     user_history.F_APPROVE=1 AND
                                     user_history.F_VERIFY=1 AND
                                     GC_NEGERI = '{$_SESSION['STATE']}'
                                     ORDER BY user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN");
                                 
                                     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                 
                                     while($row = fetch_array($result))
                                     {
                                             echo "<tr><td>";
                                             echo $j+1;
                                             echo "</td>";
                                             
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["NRIC"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["NAME"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["JABATAN"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["PTJ"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["PERINGKAT"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["PERANAN"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["MODULE"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["SC_PROGRAM"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                         
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo '<input type="checkbox"  name="chkboxapp[]" disabled="disabled" checked>';
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["REMARK_APPROVE"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                         
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo '<input type="checkbox"  name="chkboverr[]" disabled="disabled" checked>';
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo $row["REMARK_VERIFY"];
                                             echo "</td>";
                                 
                                             echo "<td>";
                                             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" class="cbgroup1" value="'.$row['ID_CAPAIAN_D'].'">';
                                             echo "</td>";
                                             
                                 
                                             $j++;
                                 
                                     }  
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Bil.</th>
                                        <th>ID </th>
                                        <th>Nama</th>
                                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                                        <th>PTJ</th>
                                        <th>Peringkat</th>
                                        <th>Peranan</th>
                                        <th>Modul</th>
                                        <th>Capaian</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Catatan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Catatan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Muat Turun <input class="form-check-input-insideHeader" type="checkbox"
                                                id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'chkbox[]')">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                            <input type="submit" name="export" value="Muat Turun" class="btn btn-info float-right" /> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:18px"></i>
                    Rekod Telah Dimuat Turun
                </div>
                <div class="card-body-tbm">

                  
                        <div class=" table-responsive">
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Bil.</th>
                                        <th>ID </th>
                                        <th>Nama</th>
                                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                                        <th>PTJ</th>
                                        <th>Peringkat</th>
                                        <th>Peranan</th>
                                        <th>Modul</th>
                                        <th>Capaian</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Catatan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Catatan BN Pengesah</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php displayExportedRecord() ?>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Bil.</th>
                                        <th>ID </th>
                                        <th>Nama</th>
                                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                                        <th>PTJ</th>
                                        <th>Peringkat</th>
                                        <th>Peranan</th>
                                        <th>Modul</th>
                                        <th>Capaian</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Catatan Pegawai Pengawal</th>
                                        <th>Kelulusan BN Pengesah</th>
                                        <th>Catatan BN Pengesah</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                           
                        </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

</div>
```

My export & encryption program:

```
if (isset($_POST['export'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['chkbox'])){
        $data=implode(',', $_POST['chkbox']);
        $result=query("SELECT DISTINCT NRIC, NAME, g1.ISPEKSCODE AS GENDER , g2.ISPEKSCODE AS RACE, g3.ISPEKSCODE AS RELIGION, g4.ISPEKSCODE AS TITLE, g5.ISPEKSCODE AS REASON,
        SC_POSITION, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY, POSTCODE, GC_NEGERI, GC_DAERAH, PHONEHOME, PHONEMOBILE, PHONEOFFICE, EMAIL, F_PTJADMIN, user_main.STATUS, STATUSREASON, ID_CAPAIAN_D  
        FROM user_main
        JOIN user_capaian ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian.USER_MAIN_NRIC 
        JOIN user_capaian_d ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian_d.USER_MAIN_NRIC AND user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN=user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN
        JOIN gc_d g1 ON g1.ID=user_main.GC_GENDER
        JOIN gc_d g2 ON g2.ID=user_main.GC_RACE
        JOIN gc_d g3 ON g3.ID=user_main.GC_RELIGION
        JOIN gc_d g4 ON g4.ID=user_main.GC_PERSONTITLE 
        JOIN gc_d g5 ON g5.ID=user_main.STATUSREASON
        WHERE ID_CAPAIAN_D IN ($data)
        ORDER BY ID_CAPAIAN_D");
        //File naming
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date=date("Ymd");
        $timestamp=date("His");
        $agencycode='60002'; 
        $statecode=$_SESSION['STATECODE']; //Later read from SESSION
        $trancode='SPI';
        $filename= './uploads/'. $statecode. '_'. $agencycode. '_'. $trancode. '_'. $date. $timestamp;
        if (ob_get_contents()) ob_end_clean();
        $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
        while($row = fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    //Header 
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (0, 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    /*Later read from DB flag*/
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (1, 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");


                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['NRIC'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['NAME'], 80, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['GENDER'], 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['RACE'], 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['RELIGION'], 10, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['TITLE'], 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['SC_POSITION'], 20, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['ADDRESS1'], 50, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['ADDRESS2'], 50, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['ADDRESS3'], 50, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['CITY'], 30, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['POSTCODE'], 5, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['GC_NEGERI'], 3, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['GC_DAERAH'], 3, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['PHONEHOME'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['PHONEMOBILE'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['PHONEOFFICE'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['EMAIL'], 50, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['F_PTJADMIN'], 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['STATUS'], 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");

                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['REASON'], 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|".PHP_EOL);

                }

                $result1=query("SELECT NRIC, user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN, g7.PERIHALCODE AS ROLE, g6.ISPEKSCODE AS LEVEL, sc_jabatan.JABATANCODE AS JABATAN, sc_ptj.PTJCODE AS PTJ, MAXAPPROVE, user_capaian_d.STATUS AS STATUS_CAPAIAN, user_history.TRAN_TYPE AS TRAN_TYPE 
                FROM user_main
                JOIN user_capaian ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian.USER_MAIN_NRIC 
                JOIN user_capaian_d ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian_d.USER_MAIN_NRIC AND user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN=user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN
                JOIN gc_d g6 ON g6.ID=user_capaian.GC_LEVEL
                JOIN gc_d g7 ON g7.ID=user_capaian.GC_ROLE
                JOIN sc_jabatan ON sc_jabatan.ID=user_capaian.SC_JABATAN
                JOIN sc_ptj ON sc_ptj.ID=user_capaian.SC_PTJ
                JOIN user_history ON user_capaian_d.USER_HISTORY_ID=user_history.ID
                JOIN sc_maxapprove ON user_capaian.SC_MAXAPPROVE=sc_maxapprove.ID
                WHERE ID_CAPAIAN_D IN ($data) 
                ORDER BY user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN");
        
                $j=0;
    
                while($row = fetch_array($result1))
                {
                    //Details Section 1
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (1, 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    if ($row['TRAN_TYPE'] == 'N' && $row['STATUS_CAPAIAN'] == '1'){
                        fwrite($handle, str_pad (1, 1, " " ));
                        fwrite($handle, "|");
                    }
                    
                    else if ($row['TRAN_TYPE'] == 'K' && $row['STATUS_CAPAIAN'] == '1') {
                        fwrite($handle, str_pad (1, 1, " " ));
                        fwrite($handle, "|");
                    }
                    
                    else if ($row['TRAN_TYPE'] == 'K' && $row['STATUS_CAPAIAN'] == '0') {
                        fwrite($handle, str_pad (2, 1, " " ));
                        fwrite($handle, "|");
                    }
                    
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['NRIC'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
                    
                    $i=$j+1;
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($j+1, 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (strtoupper($row['ROLE']), 15, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['LEVEL'], 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['JABATAN'], 6, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['PTJ'], 8, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
                    
                    /*Betulkan data type at DB so takde decimal*/
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['MAXAPPROVE']*100, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
                    fwrite($handle, "|".PHP_EOL);
                    
                    $j++;
                    
                   
                    
                    
                }
    
                $result2=query("SELECT *  
                FROM user_main JOIN user_capaian ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian.USER_MAIN_NRIC JOIN user_capaian_d 
                ON user_main.NRIC=user_capaian_d.USER_MAIN_NRIC AND user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN=user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN 
                WHERE ID_CAPAIAN_D IN ($data)
                ORDER BY user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN");
    
               $i=0;
               while($row = fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    //Details Section 2
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (2, 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    /*Later read from DB flag*/
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad (1, 1, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['NRIC'], 12, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($i+1, 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['SC_MODULE'], 2, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|");
    
                    fwrite($handle, str_pad ($row['SC_PROGRAM'], 9, " " ));
                    fwrite($handle, "|".PHP_EOL);
                   
                   $i++;
                   
                   
                }
        
                

                $update=query ("UPDATE user_capaian, user_capaian_d, user_history 
                SET user_capaian.F_FILESTATUS = 'D', user_capaian_d.F_FILESTATUS = 'D', user_history.F_FILESTATUS = 'D', user_history.FILE_DATE=CURDATE() 
                WHERE user_capaian.ID_CAPAIAN=user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN 
                AND user_capaian_d.USER_HISTORY_ID=user_history.ID
                AND user_capaian_d.ID_CAPAIAN_D IN ($data)");
                
            
                fclose($handle);
                
                if($_SESSION['STATE'] == "MLK"){
                    $fingerprint = "62C1347DC784934E5AE45EC3530C818C80CB1CC9";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "SGR"){
                    $fingerprint = "F7DC65FC269D38B97B06D4F3AB5E8847530D8DD9";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATET'] == "TRG"){
                    $fingerprint = "CB416DC6B06BF74D1C8DA888A52533206F67E0CD";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "PNG") {
                    $fingerprint = "EC8CE0BE7B23EA3D2969858A1D24DD9716B64005";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "PLS"){
                    $fingerprint = "75CA4D4E525241D14B714D9DE706513A46C8C7D7";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "PRK"){
                    $fingerprint = "C7C098D390E79AA626DC8E8D012D3E9F85D3C63A";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "PHG"){
                    $fingerprint = "46F266E23F41EE94DA1377554A6D7FEF04B4DCE6";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "NSN"){
                    $fingerprint = "30025FDBC0E79E8C2E1148D0125D82F17DE6C2E8";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "KTN"){
                    $fingerprint = "5776099FFF84A5473FD8B5FAB00E884573A9E8A9";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "KDH"){
                    $fingerprint = "747CB3F813740163AED4F44B7B16B2FABD9ECDC2";
                }

                elseif ($_SESSION['STATE'] == "JHR"){
                    $fingerprint = "C87E98DAC9FD48E6A372C1399C0E3DA66F220C2D";
                }
                   
                putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/vagrant/.gnupg');
                $gpg = new gnupg();
                $gpg -> addencryptkey($fingerprint);
                $plain=file_get_contents($filename);
                $enc=$gpg->encrypt($plain);
                file_put_contents( $filename.'.gpg', $enc);
                echo $enc;

                
                $file='./uploads/' . $filename . '.gpg';
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                readfile($file);
                exit;
    }

    else {
        alertBNAdmin("Sila masukkan pilihan fail yang ingin dimuat turun!");
        
    }

}
```

And the error that i get:

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for ./uploads/./uploads/10_60002_SPI_20201215112335.gpg in /var/www/html/isams/tryExport.php on line <i>277</i></th></tr>
Warning: readfile(./uploads/./uploads/10_60002_SPI_20201215112335.gpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/isams/tryExport.php on line <i>278</i></th></tr>
```

Comment: Paste your relevant code and exact error message here.

Comment: @rrd i've edit my post. Is it because of incorrect folder path? Anyway thanks in advanced!

Comment: Pretty sure that `./uploads/./uploads/` is not correct, and should be just a single `./uploads/` … right?

Comment: @CBroe i just realized that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Just realized that the folder path from the error is incorrect. I remove the folder path at the download code from:

```
$file='./uploads/' . $filename . '.gpg';
```

To:

```
$file= $filename . '.gpg';
```

Thank you everyone! :)